# Don't PHP strings like multiple variable insertions?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, oracle-call-interface, ora-00904

I'm using PHP 5.2 with [Oracle Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database) 11.1.

The code

```
$query = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE PINID=$pinID and COMMENTID=$commentID");
```

results in this error:

> **Warning**:  oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-00904: "COMMENTS": invalid identifier in **C:\IODwww\hello.php** on line **159**
>   ^

But running this works fine:

```
$query = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE PINID=$pinID and COMMENTID=1");
```

Is this a result of me injecting multiple variables into the query string, or am I making some other mistake?

Comment: Are you sure you have a variable named "commentID", capitalized exactly like that?

Comment: are you sure $commentId is defined?

Comment: Double-check the contents of your variables, as your PHP syntax is valid.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code where `$commentID` is assigned a value…

Comment: yup it's on of the functions parameters. Would it help to post the whole function?

Comment: In my debugging I changed the code a bit and now I have a new error: "<b>Warning</b>:  oci_execute() [<a href='function.oci-execute'>function.oci-execute</a>]: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement in <b>C:\IODwww\hello.php</b> on line <b>165</b><br />." All I'm doing differently is building the query in a new variable and then passing that to oci_parse. The new query still echoes as "SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE PINID=6 and COMMENTID=1"

Comment: Does it execute? It seems to be giving you a Warning, not an Error.

Comment: no it quits with a fatal error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with multiple variables in a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) string.

To debug the problem, you can try:

```
var_dump("SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE PINID=$pinID and COMMENTID=$commentID");
```

and see if the output really matches:

```
string(...) "SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE PINID=1 and COMMENTID=1"
```

The only things I can think of is that commentID is empty or contains a "\n" or something attached to it that causes the error.

The errorcode the database puts out, "The column name entered is either missing or invalid.", doesn't make much sense to me if works with `=1`.

Comment: I get string(52) "SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE PINID=6 and COMMENTID=1"

Answer (score 3):

For both performance and SQL Injection reasons, you should be using [placeholder variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php), like so:

```
$query = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE PINID = :pinID and COMMENTID = :commentID");
oci_bind_by_name($query, ':pinID', $pinID, -1, SQLT_INT);
oci_bind_by_name($query, ':commentID', $commentID, -1, SQLT_INT);
oci_execute($query);
```

Comment: Argh, sorry, PHP's short link for that function goes to the old version.  The real link is http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php

Answer (score 2):

`oci_execute()`'s warning is not a PHP warning. There is something wrong with the resulting query.

Print it out and take a look at it.

Comment: the resulting query (before oci_parse) is this "SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE PINID=6 and COMMENTID=1". Afterwards the query is" Resource id #3"

Comment: `ORA-00904: &quot;COMMENTS&quot;: invalid identifier`: The database does not know what COMMENTS is. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the variables within brackets:

```
$query = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE PINID={$pinID} and COMMENTID={$commentID}");
```

Also make sure that `$commentID` is not returning a blank value which would leave just `COMMENTID=` at the end and would cause an error when trying to run the query.

Comment: the brackets aren't changing my results. If I build the query and then echo it I get this:

    SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE PINID=6 and COMMENTID=1